# Best database for Node.js app using websockets

Tags: database, node.js

I am learning Node.js and the simple app I am creating will store 3 values in a database: latitude, longitude, message.

The app will then pull out any message that is located within a certain distance from your current location. The websockets just keeps your location up to date if you move around.

I know how I would do this using MySQL, but I thought there might be a more appropriate database that works well with Node.js.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Any key-value store is perfect for node.js since they store data as native JS objects or JSON.

Some popular ones include:

- MongoDB
- Redis
- Couch
- Riak

Here's a list of database modules for node.js: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#database

Comment: In a key-value database could I search for all entries where 10 < latitude < 20? I've been trying to figure out redis, but as far as I can tell I can only access data by the key.

Comment: mongoDB has geospacial indexing: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Comment: Brilliant, I've installed MongoDB and using it's shell is so easy. Which plugins should I install for Node.js to use it with socket.io and expressjs?

Comment: You can use sorted sets to do range queries with Redis.

Answer (score 1):

Check out GeoCouch:

http://vmx.cx/cgi-bin/blog/index.cgi/geocouch-the-future-is-now%3A2010-05-03%3Aen%2CCouchDB%2CPython%2CErlang%2Cgeo

It lets you do spatial queries with CouchDB.  It is very easy to talk to CouchDB from node.js because the API is JSON over HTTP.